# Range filter for count of documents with the same value for a field

Tags: elasticsearch

In my index `my-books`, each document represents a book and has a field `authorId`, which uniquely represents the author of the book. I want to run a search query with a range filter on the total number of books authored by the book's author.

For example: say, if I have four authors `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.

- `A` is the author for books `a1`, `a2`,`a3`.
- `B` is the author for book  `b1`.
- `C` is the author for books `c1`,`c2`.
- `D` is the author for books `d1`, `d2`, `d3`, `d4`.

Lets say I want to retrieve all books such as the number of books written by the same author is greater than `1` but less than `4`. Then my result hits are `[a1, a2, a3, c1, c2]`.

How do I write such a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

1. [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to  group by authors
2. [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to get documents under that author
3. [bucket_selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) to get terms where doc count is less than 4

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "author.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "books": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        },
        "final_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "values": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.values < 4"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "NAME" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "A",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "books" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index148",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "-_pOUHoBVZyA6L_G1XrM",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "book" : "a1",
                    "author" : "A"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "index148",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "_PpPUHoBVZyA6L_GL3q5",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "book" : "a3",
                    "author" : "A"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "B",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "books" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index148",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "_fpPUHoBVZyA6L_GWHpg",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "book" : "b1",
                    "author" : "B"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "C",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "books" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index148",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "_vpPUHoBVZyA6L_Gmnoj",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "book" : "c1",
                    "author" : "C"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you! However, the output hits here are bucketed, can we instead have them flattened into a flat list of documents (ready for additional filtering or sorting or whatever)?

Comment: @bappak  In  terms aggregation it wont be possible  to flatten out documents. This might be best solved by restructuring the documents and adding a author_book_count field

Comment: I think the author_book_count field would need to be a live field in that case. I have posted another question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68183480/a-live-count-field-in-elasticsearch-documents.